# Правильное регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как в терминах юникодовских регулярных выражений должно выглядеть выражение: Любой символ, исключая любое слово из любого алфавита мира и любое число?

Любой символ, исключая любое слово из любого алфавита мира выражается в виде:

```
\\P{L}+
```

Любой символ, исключая любое число:

```
\\P{N}
```

Но как из этого получить регулярное выражение, которые бы рассматривало любой символ, за исключением числа или любого слова из любого алфавита

Ниже прилагаю ссылку на сайт юникодовских регулярных выражений
https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно либо объединить классы не-букв и не цифр при помощи [пересечения символьных классов](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) `&&`:

```java
public static noLettersAndDigits(@NotNull String str) {
    return str.matches("[\\P{L}&&\\P{N}]+");
}
```

или воспользоваться ["вычитанием" `[^]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) для классов букв `p{L}` и цифр `p{N}`:

```java
public static noLettersAndDigits(@NotNull String str) {
    return str.matches("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+");
}
```